# How to receive payments with NFC on my smartphone

Tags: flutter, nfc, payment

I would like to develop an application that works as NFC-Reader (Like a POS). What kind of information should I watch out for? Can I develop it or is external hardware required?

Thank you

Comment: did you find anything?  i want to build such app.